# What did the word "Ade" mean in the English of a hundred years ago?

Tags: meaning-in-context, abbreviations, proper-nouns, twentieth-century-english, hypocorisms

Saw this in the news today and think I see the word Ade, but have never seen it before.  Is it Ade?  Or Ode?  Wde?  What does it mean?  Is it an abbreviation?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a request to decipher handwriting' the word in question actually being a name rather than part of the English lexis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **English**
>
> *Etymology:*
>   The surname derives from medieval forms of *Adam* or *Adrian*.
>
> *Proper noun:*
>   **Ade**
>
> A surname​.
>   (rare) A male given name – [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ade)

From [Graham](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/131804/graham)'s comment:

> As an example of this in English names, Adrian Edmondson is known as "Ade" to his friends, as demonstrated by the URL of his [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ade_Edmondson) page.